# How can I play sound from as root from a system script / from the lock or login screen?

Tags: sound, alsa, lock-screen

I'm trying to play a sound when I resume from sleep.  I am first trying to run amixer to set up the volume the way I want it, but when try to do this in my script (run as root) I get the error: `PulseAudio: Unable to connect: Access denied`.  If I try to just run `play` I get the error: `ALSA lib pcm_dmix.c:1052:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) unable to open slave`.

If I create a script containing `amixer` and `play` commands, and run it using `su -c /home/michael/play.sh -l michael` the amixer command throws  an error about not being able to find any devices.  I thought maybe it was a race condition with Alsa re-spawning after a resume, but even sitting in a loop, it never terminates:

```
OK=0
N=0
while [ "$OK" = "0" ]; do
    amixer -q -c 1 get Master
    OK=$?
    sleep 0.1
    let N=$N+1
done
```

If I instead just run the `play` command, the sound does not play at all until I actually get past the lock screen, at which point the `play` command immediately starts playing the sound - as if it was blocked on not having an unlocked window manager.  Even more puzzling, if I run play *as me* directly in the screen lid script (in /etc/acpi, instead of the spawned script), I get the *same* error as if I run it as root!

How can I run amixer and play immediately upon resume (or as soon as sound has re-initialized) while the lock screen is still present?